# Debian 8 jessie wacom tablet

Tags: debian, kde

When i try create profile or change settings in Wacom Tablet Settings, it brings up the settings window, along with a notification saying "Graphic Tablet error. Profile Default does not exist". I use now KDE4, GNOME works perfectly, tablet works,but i need change settings for left hand orientation

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what's up with the KDE4 control center... but a couple of other ways to accomplish it:

If it's OK to do it system-wide (for all users), you can plop it in the Xorg configuration by (as root) creating the file `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/55-local-wacom.conf` with the contents:

```
Section "InputClass"
       Identifier "Wacom Left Handed"
       MatchDriver "wacom"
       Option "Rotate" "half"
EndSection
```

I think there should be an empty `xorg.conf.d` directory by default, if not, you'll have to `mkdir` it.

Alternatively, you can also use the `xsetwacom` command-line tool. For example,

```
$ xsetwacom list devices
Wacom Bamboo 16FG 6x8 Pen stylus        id: 12  type: STYLUS    
Wacom Bamboo 16FG 6x8 Finger touch      id: 13  type: TOUCH     
Wacom Bamboo 16FG 6x8 Pad pad           id: 14  type: PAD       
Wacom Bamboo 16FG 6x8 Pen eraser        id: 16  type: ERASER    

$ xsetwacom set "Wacom Bamboo 16FG 6x8 Pen stylus" "Rotate" "half"
$ xsetwacom set "Wacom Bamboo 16FG 6x8 Finger touch" "Rotate" "half"
$ xsetwacom set "Wacom Bamboo 16FG 6x8 Pen eraser" "Rotate" "half"
```